# run full php-script in ajax/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Sorry for my bad english. I'm trying to run a PHP function through an ajax script. The PHP script should run as a FULL NORMAL php script. My idea is to run a recaptcha by a Submit button WITHOUT refreshing the page. That is working, but I found no way to run a normal php script after that. Here is the part of my script.

php:

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST['startattack'] )){
    $secret="********************";
    $response=$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
    $verify=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$response}");

    $captcha_success=json_decode($verify);   

    if ($captcha_success->success==false) {     
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('failed!')</script>";
    } else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('success!')</script>"; 
    }       
}
```

html:

```
<form method='post' id="myform">
    <center>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfETygTAAAAAMC7bQu5A3ZhlPv2KBrh8zIo_Nwa"></div>
    </center>
    <button type="submit" id="startattack" name="startattack" onclick="mycall()" class="btn btn-attack">Start Attack</button>
</form>
```

ajax:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('button').bind('click', function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'post.php',
                data: $('button').serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    alert('button was submitted');
                    type: 'post';
                    url: 'post.php';
                }
            });

            event.preventDefault();// using this page stop being refreshing 
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to check the recaptcha here. If correct, it should echo `correct` in PHP and I want to add feature later. The same with the `false` captcha.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify things a bit. You don't return the response in the Ajax is your main problem.

**PHP:**

Just echo the returned json from the recaptcha *(although I have no idea where you get the `g-recaptcha-response` key/value, you are not sending it anywhere)*.

```
if(isset( $_POST['startattack'] )){
    $secret   = "********************";
    // I have added a key/value in the ajax called "sitekey",
    // this might be what you are trying to retrieve?
    $response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
    echo file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$response}");
    exit;
}
```

**AJAX:**

I think since the return from the recaptcha is json anyway, just echo it and pick it up on this side:

```
$(function () {
    $('button').bind('click', function (event) {
        var statusBlock =   $('#status');
        statusBlock.text('button was submitted');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: {
                // Not sure if you are trying to pass this key or not...
                "sitekey":$('.g-recaptcha').data('sitekey'),
                "startattack":true
            },
            success: function (response) {
                var decode    = JSON.parse(response);
                var alertMsg  = (decode.success)? 'Success' : 'Failed';
                statusBlock.text('');
                alert(alertMsg);
            }
        });
        // using this page stop being refreshing 
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**Form:**

Leave a spot to post the submit status so it doesn't interfere with the return alert dialog window.

```
<form method='post' id="myform">
    <div id="status"></div>
    <center>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfETygTAAAAAMC7bQu5A3ZhlPv2KBrh8zIo_Nwa"></div>
    </center>
    <button type="submit" id="startattack" name="startattack" onclick="mycall()" class="btn btn-attack">Start Attack</button>
</form>
```